# Is there an issue with my Selection Sort code that's causing it to skip elements in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

While performing a selection sort in a C++ homework assignment, the array I'm using is having issues sorting data into exactly the right positions. I'm particularly confused as in last week's assignment, I was able to successfully sort two arrays at the same time with the correct order -- however, this week, there are pointers involved, though I'm fairly certain that shouldn't affect a sort referencing just the elements themselves.

So far, I've tried entering the following data in many different entry orders:

```
1000
500
560
750
1200
```

The loading seems to be fine referencing the actual putting-data-in, and the sort appears to be sorting some numbers properly (putting 500 first, for instance, most of the time), but I'm clearly doing something incorrectly for it to be failing to sort. I'll show some entries and outputs below.

Here's the code for my selection sort itself:

```
void selectionSort(int rentArray[], int arrayElements)
{
    int minSort = 0;
    int sortHold;
    sortHold;

    for (int x = 0; x < arrayElements - 1; x++)
    {
        sortHold = rentArray[x];            
        for (int y = x + 1; y < arrayElements; y++)
        {
            if (rentArray[y] < sortHold)
            {
                minSort = y;
                sortHold = rentArray[y];                
            }
        }
        if (minSort != x)
        {
            sortHold = rentArray[x];        
            rentArray[x] = rentArray[minSort];  
            rentArray[minSort] = sortHold;

        }

    }

}
```

Naturally, I expect the output to go from anything to sort the array into [500, 560, 750, 1000, 1200] rather than what it's going to. Some screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PROY9.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/itaHp.png

---

EDIT: Thank you to both @Akiva and @6502 for the help!

Putting a quick `minSort = x;` into the function just under `sortHold = rentArray[x];` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case no element is lower than `sortHold` you'll still check `minSort` for being different from `x` but it will be the `minSort` from last iteration making your code doing a wrong swap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset minSort where you reset sortHold (`minSort = x`)